How to use Animations in Kotlin fragments (Answered)
Edit:I found the answer myself online in other thread Shared Preferences in Fragment with Kotlin Hope that helps.
I am new to Kotlin programming and I am facing an issue with Kotlin fragments.
I want to use Animations when I click certain objects in my fragment, but I am not able to use them with the AnimationUtils.loadAnimation() function as its asking for the "context" and I am providing it the fragment.
Here is where I was getting the problem:
AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(game_fragment, R.anim.zoom_in).also {
settingsCard.startAnimation(it)
}

Here is my Kotlin Fragment file:
Note- Everything else is working perfectly fine and im only facing this problem with fragments

class game_fragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        val profile: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.profile)
        val settingsCard: CardView = view.findViewById(R.id.settingsCard)
        val settings: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.settingButton)
        val profileCard: CardView = view.findViewById(R.id.profileCard)
        val profileSaveBtn: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.ProfileSaveBtn)
        val profileCrossBtn: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.crossBtnProfile)
        val settingsCrossBtn: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.crossBtnSetting)
        val click = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(game, R.anim.click)



        val constraintLayoutIdProfileInfo =
            view.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.constraintLayoutIdProfileInfo)
        val constraintLayoutIdSetting =
            view.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.constraintLayoutIdSettings)



        settings.setOnClickListener {
            settings.startAnimation(click)
            visible(constraintLayoutIdSetting)
            visible(settingsCard)
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(game_fragment, R.anim.zoom_in).also {
                settingsCard.startAnimation(it)
            }
            settingsCrossBtn.setOnClickListener {
                AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(game_fragment, R.anim.zoom_out).also {
                    settingsCard.startAnimation(it)
                    Handler().postDelayed({
                        gone(constraintLayoutIdSetting)
                        gone(settingsCard)
                    }, 500)
                }
            }

        }
                return view

    }


    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment game.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            game_fragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }



}

I can also provide my XML file but it doesn't have any issues.
Thanks
I tried using this code:
AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(game_fragment, R.anim.zoom_in).also {
settingsCard.startAnimation(it)
}

And I also tried to change it from game_fragment to game_fragment() and even to the activity in which these fragments are i.e. "game" but the result was same and the app couldn't run or crash
